# Add pictures or schematics in this forum

Tags: discussion

Please tell me how to add a picture or an electronic leds schematic design to an answer.
When we are asking we have some symbols in the frame to add pictures **but what when we are answering?**

Thanks

Comment: You can add them in the same way, using the schematic and image tools in the editor.

Comment: You can add pictures, schematics, etc. when posting an answer, but not when posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The CircuitLab tool can be used to draw and insert a schematic in a question or an answer. Desktop site only.

You can also post pictures if that’s easier. Desktop or mobile site.

Comments don’t support pictures or schematics, limit text formatting to *italic* or **bold**, and don’t support line breaks.